# Can't find warehouse in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I created a database with some tables by hive.

In hive-site.xml, I set "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" default to "/user/hive/warehouse"

but there isn't such a directory in hdfs

Where else can I find the related files to my database and tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `describe formatted <table_name>` and check the line with LOCATION, it will tell you where your directories and files are for your tables.